# How to total quantity based on date range from another table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

how to total `quantity` based on `date` range from another table?

```
var items = entity.ItemHeaders.Where(x => x.date >= _dateFrom && x.date <= dateTo);
var tQty =  entity.ItemContents.Where(x => x.Warehouse == dto.Warehouse).Sum(x => x.Quantity);
```

the problem is I don't have any idea how to connect them.

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with mvc.

Comment: When i read this I get confused.  Maybe i dont understand. The total quantity of what? The entire date range?  Can you please elaborate.

Comment: What's the relation between ItemHeader and ItemContent?

Comment: @Jamin. yes. the total quantity of entire date range.

Comment: @EvanHuang ItemContent has foreign key in ItemHeader. which is named as HeaderNumber..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the entity by HeaderNumber and sum the total:

```
var total = (from header in entity.ItemHeaders
            from content in entity.ItemContents
            where header.date >= _dateFrom && header.date <= dateTo
               && content.Warehouse == dto.Warehouse
               && header.ID = content.HeaderNumber
            select content.Quantity).Sum();
```

Assuming you are using Entity Framework, it will be easier if you have a Navigation Property defined in ItemContent for the ItemHeader. e.g.:

```
public virtual ItemHeader Header {get; set;}
```

Then the query could be:

```
var total = entity.ItemContents
            .Where(x=> x.Header.date >= _dateFrom && x.Header.date <= dateTo 
                    && x.Warehouse == dto.Warehouse)
            .Sum(x => x.Quantity);
```